# Show Lipschitz continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I'm stuck trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ a function with the property that, for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$, there is  $L=L(v) > 0$ such that the function $t \mapsto f(x+tv)$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Show that f is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Is this your homework? If so, please tag it, thanks.

Comment: What am I supposed to tag?

Comment: Sorry, I missed [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what). There is now no homework tag, and it is fine to just leave it as it is now. :")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that for $v_1,v_2\in S^{n-1}$ we have that
$$
 |f(x+v_1t_1+v_2t_2)- f(x)| \\= 
  |f(x+v_1t_1+v_2t_2)-f(x+v_1 t_1)+f(x+v_1 t_1) -f(x)| 
\\\leq |t_2|L(v_2) + |t_2|L(v_1)
$$

Now take an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define
$$
 L_i =  L(e_i)
$$ 
to get
$$
 |f(x+ \sum_i t_i e_i)-f(x)| \leq \sum_i |t_i| L_i \leq \sqrt{\sum_i |t_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_i L_i^2}= |\sum_i t_i e_i|\sqrt{\sum_i L_i^2}.
$$
hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $\sqrt{\sum_i L_i^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One question: What does your $S^{n-1}$ refer to?

Comment: And I did not really understand if $t$ is a vector or a number. Is $t \in \mathbb R$ or $t \in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: $S^{n-1}$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}$ and all $t$'s are scalars. Sorry

Comment: Thanks so much! You don't have to be sorry, was just me needing some additional info in order to understand you.